# What is the most natural way to disambiguate "with"?

Tags: disambiguation

In Spanish, if you say "I'm with X", it implies that you are not part of X. But in English, although both interpretations are possible, the converse is the usual.

If you say "I'm an officer with the NYPD", it means you are part of the NYPD. But let's consider the following example: you are an American soldier about to attack the Nazis together with British and Canadian fellows, and you say "I'm with the 2nd British Army", meaning you are going to attack alongside them, as allies, not that you are a member of the 2nd British Army.

My question is what is the most usual way to disambiguate these two meanings of "with" in English.

Comment: Would this do it? "I'm here with the 2nd British Army."

Comment: Your soldier, unless he had been seconded to the British Army as an individual, would be there with others of his own unit, so he would say _'We are_ with the British 2nd Army'.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "I'm with X" _normally_ means that you are part of X, just that that it _sometimes_ does depending on the context. In the very specific case of "A is a B with X" where A is a person, B is a role or position and X is an organisation then you are generally correct but without the role or postion then it really can mean either. For instance someone might answer a phone and say "I can't speak at the moment I'm with Smith and Co". In this case you would normally assume that Smith and Co were clients or potential customers.

Comment: "I'm with stupid -->"

Answer (score 1):

You can disambiguate the first sense by saying "in" instead of "with".

> I'm an officer in the NYPD.

I'm not sure if there's a universal way to disambiguate the 2nd case, but there may be specific terms appropriate to different situations. For example,

> a reporter embedded with the Army Rangers

or

> a British soldier seconded to the US Air Force

or

> a groupie following Kanye West

but the appropriate terms will depend on the specific circumstance.

Comment: I would add, "I am an American soldier attached to the British 2nd Army.

Comment: @RobJarvis, trying to make an exhaustive list of these terms would be impossible.